# how to access a UITableV in heightForRowAtIndexPath in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a custom tablecell with three labels. If a label is empty, i hide it. 
In my **Objective-C** Version

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailCell *cell = (DetailCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat height = 84.0;
    if (IsEmpty(cell.lblArt.text))
        height -= 24;

    if (IsEmpty(cell.lblTelefon.text))
        height -= 24;

    return height;
}
```

i have this result:

[image]

In heightForRowAtIndexPath i must access the cell to calculate the height based on the hidden labels. This is one of my tries in **Swift**:

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    let cell:DetailCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as DetailCell // ????????

    var height:CGFloat = 84.0;

    if cell.lblArt.text.isEmpty{
        height -= 24
    }
    if cell.lblTelefon.text.isEmpty{
        height -= 24        }

    return height;
}
```

But i can't get the cell, here starts a never-ending loop. :-(

How can i do that in Swift?

Comment: Please specify what the problem is (what error comes up?).

Comment: You shouldn't be inspecting the cells to find out if labels have text in them etc... You should be inspecting the data model that you use to populate them in the first place.

Comment: @influxd: a never ending loop...

Comment: @Fogmeister where should i inspect the cell? At the custom class?

Comment: Ideally, nowhere. You will somewhere have an array (or something) that populates the labels in the table view with the telephone numbers etc... You should be inspecting this array to find out if the telephone number exists. Not the cells. The cells should really never be "looked" at.

Comment: my question is: how can i get the cell in self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

Comment: And my answer is: Don't. You should be accessing the data not the view. What is your code for the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? If you show us that I can explain what I mean but at the moment there isn't much to go on.

Comment: @Fogmeister: the content comes from Core-Data, that i inspect in a SQLITE-Bowser. In swift and Objective-C they are the same

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is. Use this data that comes from Core-Data to find if the telephone number exists. Don't use the UILabel in the cell. Use the data. You already have the data (you used it to put the telephone number on the screen) so use it again.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are inspecting the cell to try and find if the telephone number exists. This is the wrong way to go about this completely.

In your code for `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you will have something like this..

```
- (UItableViewCell*)tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do some stuff

    // get a telephone number from the data
    NSString *theTelephoneNumber = //get something from core data    

    // set the text in the label in the cell
    cell.lblTelefon.text = theTelephoneNumber;

    return cell;
}
```

So in your method for `height` you should be doing this...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *theTelephoneNumber = //get something from core data
    // this is the same as the above method

    CGFloat height = 84.0;

    if ([theTelephoneNumber isEqualToString:@""]) {
        height -= 24;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Don't go to the view to get data. Go to the data to get data.